"overlayView?.isClickable = false" is not working in android 12
This are my variables
private var overlayView: View? = View(context) // Initialize overlayView here

private val mParams: WindowManager.LayoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FIRST_SYSTEM_WINDOW,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
            or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
            or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
            or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
            or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
)

private val mWindowManager: WindowManager

This is one of the view over screen but is not working as I aspect, overlayView?.isClickable = false is not working and this problem is only in android 12, is working in the app but when I exit from the app is not working anymore.
"Flashing green(Top Screen)" -> {

    val screenHeight = context.resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels
    val halfScreenHeight = screenHeight / 2
    mParams.x = 0
    mParams.y = -halfScreenHeight
    mParams.height = screenHeight

    val flickerRunnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            isGreen = !isGreen
            val color = if (isGreen) Color.GREEN else Color.TRANSPARENT
            overlayView?.setBackgroundColor(color)

            handler.postDelayed(this, 10) // Adjust the flickering speed as needed
        }
    }

    fun stopFlicker() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(flickerRunnable)
        overlayView?.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

    }

    fun startFlicker() {
        handler.post(flickerRunnable)
        handler.postDelayed({
            stopFlicker()
            handler.postDelayed({
                startFlicker()
            }, 6000) // Restart after 4 seconds
        }, 2000) // Stop after 4 seconds
    }

    startFlicker()

    overlayView?.isClickable = false
    overlayView?.isFocusable = false
    overlayView?.isFocusableInTouchMode = false
}


can you show layout/xml file?

What does "is not working" mean ... ?
